# How to use list values as string in 'IN' clause? Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

DB: Redshift.
There is a separated list of ids as a string. I need to use it in an IN construct, approximately like this:

```
WITH test_data AS (
  SELECT 1 AS c
  UNION
  SELECT 2
  UNION
  SELECT 10
  UNION
  SELECT 100
)
SELECT * FROM test_data 
WHERE c IN (SELECT '1,2,3,4,5')
```

What is the best way?

I tried to expand it into an array, but something went wrong

```
WITH test_data AS (
  SELECT 1 AS c
  UNION
  SELECT 2
  UNION
  SELECT 10
  UNION
  SELECT 100
)
SELECT * FROM test_data 
WHERE c::text = any (SELECT string_to_array('1,2,3,4,5',',') );
```

`error: operator does not exist: character varying = text[]`

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into separate values:

```sql
WHERE c IN (
  SELECT unnest(string_to_array('1,2,3,4,5', ',')::int[])
);
```